# When should Loader be preferred over createQmlObject and vice versa - QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Both can create objects dynamically.
When should `Loader` be preferred over `Qt.createQmlObject` and vice versa in QML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Loader` can be regarded as a placeholder for a particular object. It also gives you the ability to reference the underlying object through the `Loader`'s id.

`Qt.createQmlObject` is generally more powerful than a `Loader`, because you can instantiate as many objects as you want, and also it doesn't have the overhead of the `Loader`. But you have to take care to keep track of what you create in order to be able to reference it.

The other functions `Qt.createComponent()` and then `createObject()` offer similar advantages, plus the possibility to pass properties to be used in the object's creation instead of setting them only after it has been created.

I personally see very little point in `Loader` and rarely use it, if at all in production code. IMO it was introduced for the sake of the "non-programmer" much like most of the recent development, such as the new designer and QML `.ui` files, which I find kind of annoying, but it is understandable - trying to increase adoption by non-programmers.

Comment: Very little point in `Loader`? Have you ever built a real QQ2 application, with hundreds of source files? Hiding invisible screens behind `Loader`s makes your app appear on screen in 1 second instead of 10 seconds.

Comment: @peppe the `Loader` does no magic, it is no faster than dynamically instantiating objects, but it is heavier. In apps with lots of components I pre-load and keep the components in memory to instantiate faster. If you can do dynamic object instantiation right, `Loader` is just overhead and source pollution. Furthermore `Loader` has nothing to do with "invisible screens", whatever those might be. If by that you mean invisible component sitting idle - that just wastes memory, IMO modern hardware is fast enough to make CPU cycles a good investment to save memory, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: I didn't say it does magic, I said that the dynamic instantiation offered by `Loader` is a thing used in any non-trivial QQ2 application.

Comment: And I said "**I personally** see very little point in `Loader`" - your experience may vary.

Comment: `also it doesn't have the overhead of the Loader` Please mention what are the overheads of a Loader with references to your claims. Thanks.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius - each loader is hundreds of bytes, possibly thousands. It also takes time to instantiate like everything else.